# What is it about this question that it's getting upvotes and positive comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

The answer does not include anything about comfort, which is the root of the question. The answer and the comments just pile on against a person who would use the product. What is wrong with this place?

The answer should be a comment, but there's so much group-think that people's judgment is clouded.

*[How comfortable is it to wear a u-lock holder this way?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/44265/19730)*

Comment: Are you offended by that answer because (by your answer) you wear something similar?

Answer (score 9):

It's not a particularly great question, but it's getting upvotes because people generally have a sense of humor. The most popular answer is humorous but at the expense of a particular subset of cyclist that the rest of the population tends to poke fun at. Not saying this is appropriate or acceptable behavior, just answering your question...

The site, and particularly site moderation, only works if users make a reasonable effort on their own to police behavior. In this particular case, no one as voted to close the question for any reason (like "primarily opinion based") nor has anyone flagged any of the answers or comments.

If, in the future, you see problem questions or answers your best bet is to use the "vote to close" and "flag for moderator attention" buttons.

Answer (score 3):

The question asks "does anyone have any thoughts"... what's in the answer are definitely thoughts. The fact that it's a slightly funny response to a bad question makes it worth an upvote, even though I normally downvote all answers to closed questions as a matter of course.

It's a poor question, if I'd seen it while it was open I would have voted "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Slightly funny? Just slightly funny? I'm offended!! :-)

Comment: I'm finding I really like this community.  This is part of why.